# Does Nagios Core support event handling

Tags: shell, event-handling, system, monitoring, nagios

I have a question. Does Nagios Core support event handling?

I want to monitor disk space of host machines and take actions when host status changes.

For example, if the disk space is low and host state change to critical then Nagios should take action to clean certain files may be by running some shell scripts/commands.

Is this possible? If so, then please can you share some steps/pre-requisites I should take care.

Thanks again,

Regards,
Aditi

Answer (score 0):

Yes check [Event Handlers - Official Documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html)